# PHP string Computation

Tags: php

Im doing a php activity, that will compute the sum of given number of integer.
Sample Output:

```
 int number = 367;
 Final output 
 16
```

16 is the total sum of 3+6+7.

Here's my Code:

```
$number = "367";
$int = 0;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < number.length(); $i++ ){
    $char = number.charAt(i);
    $int += Integer.parseInt(char1.toString());
}
echo $int;
```

Still i can't get the right answer anyone can help me? Thank you !

regards jay

Comment: How come you are using javascript in PHP?

Comment: its not javascript sir. -_-

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing but it seems like you're mixing PHP and Javascript. If you're looking for a PHP solution it's a lot easier than that. Give this a try:

```
$number = 367;
echo array_sum(str_split($number));
```